# ArcSDE cannot perform post installation

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, arcgis-10.2, installation

I have installed the following before I installed ArcSDE 10.2.1:

1. ArcGIS for Desktop 10.2.1(standard)
2. ArcGIS for server Enterprise 10.2.1(standard)
3. MS SQL server 2008
4. create enterprise geodatabase successfully

After I installed ArcSDE 10.2.1, when I tried to perform arcsde post installation" I cannot find it in "Start -> All Programs -> ArcSDE -> arcsde for microsoft sql server post installation", I only got "Command References" under ArcSDE.

Anything I missed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no post installation available on the latest versions of ArcSDE (since 10.1). You are suppposed to use ArcGIS Desktop GP tools for creating and managing ArcSDE enterprise geodatabase stored in an RDBMS.

Please refer to this [blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2012/03/27/where-did-the-arcsde-post-installation-wizard-go-at-10-1/) for detailed instructions.

If you don't want to direct connect, that is you want to use application server connection, then you can can manually create and register (depending on DBMS) a service using the ArcSDE administration commands.

Another great resource to go through:

[Do This, Not That! – Alternatives to using SDE command line tools](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/supportcenter/2013/10/04/do-this-not-that-alternatives-to-using-sde-command-line-tools/)

Comment: thanks a lot, I have already followed the link your provided and successfully enable enterprise geodatabase.

Comment: Great! Just to help you get updated on the changes introduced in the latest versions, I've updated my answer to include another good link.